How common is it for external contractors to manage internal teams, and how can we navigate this situation?
Context
I work as a software engineer in a team responsible for maintaining a specific component in company A. I am an employee of A and have a permanent contract with them
Myself and two other developers were hired to take ownership of the component from contracting agency B who were originally hired to build it. They had about 8 developers dedicated to creating and maintaining it. However, we quickly ran into issues - onboarding three developers and handing over a complex system within a month was a failure, and we lost a lot of domain expertise, which took a long period of inefficient trial-and-error working to regain.
Several months later, higher management in our company (correctly) decided that we needed more resources to be able to deliver our future roadmap, as we were constantly bogged down in operational issues which meant we had no capacity to dedicate to development. In response, however, instead of choosing to hire more permanent employees, they approached another contracting agency, C, who agreed to provide developers not just in our team but across the whole business.
The original plan was to have a A-company engineering manager managing a mixed team of 3 A devs and about 5 C devs.
However, the engineering manager was also given responsibility over a separate area of the business where they would merge three data teams into one. They quickly found the workload overwhelming, and stepped back from their responsibilities in our team. He would still provide line management responsibilities, but we should strive to become a "self organising team".
We found many issues slowly emerged from this. The incentives of what C had to deliver was misaligned from the job responsibilities of A devs. For instance, operational issues were not in the C contract, and so A devs were still bogged down in the exact same operational responsibilities (which continues to increase as the business expands) and did not get much of a say in the last eight months of development work. This makes us seem incompetent and C seem like "rockstars" in the eyes of management. Moreover, because there is no single source of authority, not just within the team but also within the business area (a whole other issue - we have had a fired CTO, a nontechnical COO and now two people [head of product and head of engineering] all leading the department within the last eight months with competing visions and overlapping priorities, and we now have a new CEO as well to top it all off) - and because we are a "self organising team", the C devs always outnumber us 5 to 3, and they end up leading everything with opaque internal ceremonies without consulting us.
This culminated when the upper management of A decided that C would now provide engineering management, and appointed one of their devs to manage us.
I have to say, I do enjoy working with the C devs, and they have been listening to our concerns. However, in the eyes of us A devs, this is a bizarre business structure arrangement. There is essentially a layer of C between us and the rest of the business, and we are often isolated.
Some anecdotes:

We got a new CEO, and when we met him, he referred to our team and as "the C team" and didn't know there were A devs presenty. I asked C about this, and they said they always refer to us collectively as "the XYZ team" agnostic to company, which I believe them on. But if C people are always talking to upper management then A devs don't get seen
The founder of C arranged a workshop with all the A devs (as we have the domain knowledge from handling the operational issues), and asked us how we would improve the component if we had the capacity. However, again, when the CEO talked about these ideas, he referred to them as "C ideas", even though we've been saying we need the space to develop such a solution for a long time
Our product owner left the company, and we verbally agreed as a team (both A and C) to divide his old responsibilities between different team members. However, middle management are insisting on one way of working and not allowing the team to govern themselves

Question(s)

Is it common for external contractors to assume engineering management roles over internal teams?
What best practices can be adopted when working under external engineering management to ensure internal teams are not marginalised?
Is this more likely to be a problem with using contractors in general, or does this sound like bad A management?
And finally, how can we as A devs navigate the political environment which has emerged as a result of the incentives of a contracting agency, when they control the flow of communication and authority between us and middle/higher management?


This could really use an edit for length. I honestly had trouble getting through it—it has too much detail.

Is it common -> have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interim_management

The management of your company seems like its in utter chaos.
8 experienced out-house developers who created the software were going replaced in a month by 3 new in-house developers with no experience, cue a quagmire. Your existing engineering manager went AWOL from your team due to new responsibilities, and the product owner left. The CEO left and the new one doesn't even know who you are. After a period without any governance, you've finally been handed over to a new out-house engineering manager at a completely new contracting firm. All happening within about 12 months! And you've achieved nothing but firefight the existing application since the beginning.
It sounds like management are desperately trying anything to avoid having a sufficient number of developers and managers on staff, and amongst all the impulsive reorganisations they have probably destroyed most of the furniture and the retention of knowledge and experience already.

Is it common for external contractors to assume engineering management roles over internal teams?

It's not common in how you describe, no. It sounds more like management are trying to transfer you out to the contractor, but without legal formalities of doing so - perhaps, because management's original plans for insourcing failed and they are now on a different track, back to using a contractor.

What best practices can be adopted when working under external engineering management to ensure internal teams are not marginalised?

It doesn't sound like your management want you to be central or non-marginal.

And finally, how can we as A devs navigate the political environment which has emerged as a result of the incentives of a contracting agency to take credit for work which isn't theirs, when they control the flow of communication and authority between us and middle/higher management?

I think navigating a path to the door would be the best.
Seeking and using your ideas and information - putting in legwork to gather it, applying judgment to evaluate the quality, and then coming up with a communicable plan based on it - is not necessarily contrary to what your management would expect of the contractors, or any middle managers.
But when your relationship with your own management is "Who are you, and what are you doing in here?", I really don't think you stand much of a chance of re-gaining respect. You're mere pawns in a chaotic political game, and the idea of having an in-house development team is clearly back in the grave again.

I think navigating a path to the door would be the best.  This.  Go now while the going is good.  All Team C will use Team A for is blame.  No matter what people on Team A do now, it will be sold as either a success for C's leadership of A or A's failure to cooperate with C.  There is no winning this loaded game.  Get those CV's out.

The answers to your questions all come down to respect.  Currently, on my team, we have three companies represented.  We all work wonderfully together, because there is a great deal of mutual respect.  We all help each other to advance the time line/road map.  There are some issues that we have to over come like time zone and network issues, but everyone makes their best effort to do so.
Even within my company there are hiccups.  The scrum master is a lower level then some of the team members.  But it works because those higher levels respects the job he is doing, and he respects the older, more senior guys.
I've worked on teams that were self contained within one company that performed far worse because it was nothing but back stabbing and politics.
The trouble is, with your position, you won't have much say in what goes on.

+1 - it is very common for external companies to be brought in and have responsibility. Like @pete-b I've seen it work well and be a disaster. Communication and respect is the key, you're going to have to fight for the respect and involvement you are due I'm afraid.

So it looks as if the company really wanted to press ahead at enhancements, but didn't have anyone available internally to manage those enhancements and outsourced that function right along with adding on five developers from C to work with your three developers from A.  There's really nothing inherently wrong with such a setup.
It's not unusual at all to do staff augmentation during the "build" stage of software development, and to terminate those people after deployment.  Sometimes a few are hired on permanently to do maintenance, but there's no need to keep the whole group for sporadic maintenance tasks.  Likewise, the management function will be handed off to an internal staff member after deployment.
I think you're reacting out of some notion of feeling you "own" this product personally.  It's not yours, but the company's, and management has the right to hire whoever they want to in order to get work done on it.  This notion -- LET IT GO.   It's a notion that's not serving you.
Your internal team of three is the long-term maintenance team.  Chances are that post-deployment you'll end up fixing a lot of stuff that the eight contractors didn't build correctly.  At the end of the day, you'll still have a job.  If you feel you need to be in a position to influence outcomes more directly, then brush off your resume and find a management job that in turn won't let you be as involved in development.  There will never be a 100% perfect working solution, so it would behoove you to work with a situation that's mostly right and for the other stuff, again - LET IT GO.
Good luck.

I know this isn't the favored answer, but honestly, it's the right one. As recently as a couple years ago I would have been equally upset and annoyed at all the chaos, loss of ownership, etc. I understand where you're coming from, truly. But you ultimately have no power in this situation. They're gonna do they're gonna do and they're not going to listen. What are you worried about ultimately? A bad review? You have no control over that either.

It isn't your project and it isn't your company. I assume it's not work that saves lives. It just doesn't matter. It's not worth the stress. Take the paycheck and wait it out, or find a new job.
